# How to pronounce the final “s” in plural nouns

Tags: grammatical-number, pronunciation, phonology, pronunciation-vs-spelling, consonants

Could you please help find which word below is pronounced differently from the rest with regard to the final *s*?

1. *caves*
2. *marks*
3. *exams*
4. *days*

I choose number 2, *marks*.

Comment: You have chosen wisely.

Comment: This should be moved to ELL.EU.

Answer (score 6):

"Letters" are not pronounced in English; but the plural is simple as long as you don't think of letters, but sounds.

It's

- /-s/ after voiceless consonants (/p t k f θ/)
- /-z/ after everything else.
- Plus, you have to add a shwa /ə/ **after** sibilants /s ʃ tʃ z ʒ dʒ/ **before** you add /-z/.

That's it. That's the whole rule.
It's not a spelling rule, it's a pronunciation rule.  Most rules like this are pronunciation rules.

English phoneme symbols [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/modestproposal.pdf).

Comment: Plus a final unvoiced continuant (usually) becomes voiced when adding a *-s* noun or verb inflection. It does so in *wolf > wolves, bath > baths, house > houses* but not in *cough > coughs*.

Comment: That's an irregular root change, though; it doesn't affect the suffix rule. That's in the same boat as zero plurals like _sheep_ or archaic ones like _oxen_ and _women_. Details [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler//Inflection.pdf).